# properties file to store sensitive config

Tags: android, security, encryption

Ok, so i'm in the process of planning automated builds for my android app. This means I will need to put any configuration information such as API keys and endpoints into a .properties file. The problem is that I can't just pop the API keys into that file.

I'm aware that the common recommendation is to try and obscure sensitive data inside your app and then generate it at runtime.

My plan is to encrypt the sensitive .properties data and generate it's accesskey in code.

I could store the encryption keys in a Java keystore and then derive its password in code at runtime.

This all means that I can easily swap encryption keys and and api keys easily during build for test/production environments. I can also exclude from source control.

What do you guys think of this approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan sounds good to me except storing keys inside the keystore. Basically, there is only one keystore instance created for all system-level and third-party apps on the device. After Android 4.0, the keystore is integrated with the unlock screen and it is unlocked when the user unlocked the device. So, if you store your key as a key/value pair inside the keystore, then your key is ready before you open your app. Or, if you store it as key/encrypted(value) pair, then you have to derive the key from the password at run-time and decrypt the encrypted value. But you may end up having two password for unlocking the phone screen and unlocking the key. I probably go with with only one password, i.e. screen unlock password. Since the keystore is mapped to the Process ID, it is only accessed from your app. However, if you are thinking to handle multi-user per phone, then the latter approach may be relevant.

Comment: Hi, I must support Android 2.x so I think the native keystore is not suitable, am I correct?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's correct. Sorry for delayed response. Have you sorted out?